# Why won't a React form register inputs on only 3 fields?

Tags: reactjs, forms, firebase, field, react-bootstrap

This form I'm doing in a React app was working fine until I added a few more fields. I can't figure out why I wouldn't be able to type into "first Name", "middle", or "last name" on the form.

Basically, I've tried adding the fields with the exact process that I added the other fields with, but it's just not working and I keep looking over the code and can't find out what's going on. I add everything throughout the code that all the other fields have.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { compose } from 'recompose';

import { withFirebase } from '../Firebase';
import * as ROUTES from '../../constants/routes';
import * as ROLES from '../../constants/roles';


const SignUpPage = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>SignUp</h1>
    <SignUpForm />
  </div>
);

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  username: '',
  firstName: '',
  middleName: '',
  lastName: '',
  email: '',
  passwordOne: '',
  passwordTwo: '',
  isAdmin: false,
  mailingAddress: '',
  city: '',
  state: '',
  zip: '',
  error: null,
};

class SignUpFormBase extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { ...INITIAL_STATE };
  }

  onChange = event => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };

  onSubmit = event => {

    const { username, firstName, middleName, lastName, email, passwordOne, isAdmin, mailingAddress, city, state, zip } = this.state;

    const roles = {};
    if (isAdmin) {
      roles[ROLES.ADMIN] = ROLES.ADMIN;
    }

    this.props.firebase
      .doCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, passwordOne)
      .then(authUser => {
        // Create a user in your Firebase realtime database
        return this.props.firebase
          .user(authUser.user.uid)
          .set({
            username,
            firstName,
            middleName,
            lastName,
            email,
            roles,
            mailingAddress,
            city,
            state,
            zip,
          });
      })
      .then(() => {
        return this.props.firebase.doSendEmailVerification();
      })
      .then(() => {
        this.setState({ ...INITIAL_STATE });
        this.props.history.push(ROUTES.HOME);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.setState({ error });
      });

    event.preventDefault();

  }

  onChangeCheckbox = event => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.checked });
  };

  onChangeSelection = event => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.selected });
  };

  render() {

    const {
      username,
      firstName,
      middleName,
      lastName,
      email,
      passwordOne,
      passwordTwo,
      isAdmin,
      mailingAddress,
      city,
      state,
      zip,
      error,
    } = this.state;

    const isInvalid =
      passwordOne !== passwordTwo ||
      passwordOne === '' ||
      username === '' ||
      email === '' ||
      firstName === '' ||
      lastName === ''||
      mailingAddress === '' ||
      city === '' ||
      state === '' ||
      zip === '';


    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>

        <div class="form-row">

          <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <input
              name="username"
              value={username}
              onChange={this.onChange}
              type="text"
              placeholder="Username"
              class="form-control"
            />
          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="form-row">

          <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <input
              name="firstname"
              value={firstName}
              onChange={this.onChange}
              type="text"
              placeholder="First Name"
              class="form-control"
            />
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <input
              name="middlename"
              value={middleName}
              onChange={this.onChange}
              type="text"
              placeholder="Middle Name"
              class="form-control"
            />
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <input
              name="lastname"
              value={lastName}
              onChange={this.onChange}
              type="text"
              placeholder="Last Name"
              class="form-control"
            />
          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="form-row">

          <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <input
              name="email"
              value={email}
              onChange={this.onChange}
              type="text"
              placeholder="Email Address"
              class="form-control"
            />
          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="form-row">

          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <input
              name="passwordOne"
              value={passwordOne}
              onChange={this.onChange}
              type="password"
              placeholder="Password"
              class="form-control"
            />
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <input
              name="passwordTwo"
              value={passwordTwo}
              onChange={this.onChange}
              type="password"
              placeholder="Confirm Password"
              class="form-control"
            />
          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="form-row">

          <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <label>
              Admin:
              <input
                name="isAdmin"
                type="checkbox"
                checked={isAdmin}
                onChange={this.onChangeCheckbox}
              />
            </label>
          </div>

        </div>
        <br />

        <div class="form-row">

          <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            Mailing Address:
            <input
              name="mailingAddress"
              value={mailingAddress}
              onChange={this.onChange}
              type="text"
              placeholder="Street Address"
              class="form-control"
            />
          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="form-row">

          <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <input
              name="city"
              value={city}
              onChange={this.onChange}
              type="text"
              placeholder="City"
              class="form-control"
            />
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <select id="inputState" class="form-control" value={state} onChange={this.onChangeSelection}>
              <option selected>Choose a state</option>
              <option>...</option>
            </select>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-md-1">
            <input
              name="zip"
              value={zip}
              onChange={this.onChange}
              type="text"
              placeholder="Zip Code"
              class="form-control"
            />
          </div>

        </div>

        <button disabled={isInvalid} type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
          Sign Up
        </button>

        {error && <p>{error.message}</p>}
      </form>
    );
  }
}

const SignUpLink = () => (
  <p>
    Don't have an account? <Link to={ROUTES.SIGN_UP}>Sign Up</Link>
  </p>
);

const SignUpForm = compose(
  withRouter,
  withFirebase,
)(SignUpFormBase);

export default SignUpPage;

export { SignUpForm, SignUpLink };
```

I just want the name fields to register keystrokes like the rest of the form can. Everything else works. I don't get why first, middle, and last name will only focus.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `value` to `defaultValue`. `defaultValue` only gets set on initial load for a form. After that, it won't get "naturally" updated because the intent was only to set an initial default value.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { compose } from 'recompose';

import { withFirebase } from '../Firebase';
import * as ROUTES from '../../constants/routes';
import * as ROLES from '../../constants/roles';


const SignUpPage = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>SignUp</h1>
    <SignUpForm />
  </div>
);

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  username: '',
  firstName: '',
  middleName: '',
  lastName: '',
  email: '',
  passwordOne: '',
  passwordTwo: '',
  isAdmin: false,
  mailingAddress: '',
  city: '',
  state: '',
  zip: '',
  error: null,
};

class SignUpFormBase extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { ...INITIAL_STATE };
  }

  onChange = event => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };

  onSubmit = event => {

    const { username, firstName, middleName, lastName, email, passwordOne, isAdmin, mailingAddress, city, state, zip } = this.state;

    const roles = {};
    if (isAdmin) {
      roles[ROLES.ADMIN] = ROLES.ADMIN;
    }

    this.props.firebase
      .doCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, passwordOne)
      .then(authUser => {
        // Create a user in your Firebase realtime database
        return this.props.firebase
          .user(authUser.user.uid)
          .set({
            username,
            firstName,
            middleName,
            lastName,
            email,
            roles,
            mailingAddress,
            city,
            state,
            zip,
          });
      })
      .then(() => {
        return this.props.firebase.doSendEmailVerification();
      })
      .then(() => {
        this.setState({ ...INITIAL_STATE });
        this.props.history.push(ROUTES.HOME);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.setState({ error });
      });

    event.preventDefault();

  }

  onChangeCheckbox = event => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.checked });
  };

  onChangeSelection = event => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.selected });
  };

  render() {

    const {
      username,
      firstName,
      middleName,
      lastName,
      email,
      passwordOne,
      passwordTwo,
      isAdmin,
      mailingAddress,
      city,
      state,
      zip,
      error,
    } = this.state;

    const isInvalid =
      passwordOne !== passwordTwo ||
      passwordOne === '' ||
      username === '' ||
      email === '' ||
      firstName === '' ||
      lastName === ''||
      mailingAddress === '' ||
      city === '' ||
      state === '' ||
      zip === '';


    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>

        <div class="form-row">

          <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <input
              name="username"
              defaultValue={username}
              onChange={this.onChange}
              type="text"
              placeholder="Username"
              class="form-control"
            />
          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="form-row">

          <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <input
              name="firstname"
              defaultValue={firstName}
              onChange={this.onChange}
              type="text"
              placeholder="First Name"
              class="form-control"
            />
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <input
              name="middlename"
              value={middleName}
              onChange={this.onChange}
              type="text"
              placeholder="Middle Name"
              class="form-control"
            />
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <input
              name="lastname"
              defaultValue={lastName}
              onChange={this.onChange}
              type="text"
              placeholder="Last Name"
              class="form-control"
            />
          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="form-row">

          <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <input
              name="email"
              value={email}
              onChange={this.onChange}
              type="text"
              placeholder="Email Address"
              class="form-control"
            />
          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="form-row">

          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <input
              name="passwordOne"
              value={passwordOne}
              onChange={this.onChange}
              type="password"
              placeholder="Password"
              class="form-control"
            />
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <input
              name="passwordTwo"
              value={passwordTwo}
              onChange={this.onChange}
              type="password"
              placeholder="Confirm Password"
              class="form-control"
            />
          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="form-row">

          <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <label>
              Admin:
              <input
                name="isAdmin"
                type="checkbox"
                checked={isAdmin}
                onChange={this.onChangeCheckbox}
              />
            </label>
          </div>

        </div>
        <br />

        <div class="form-row">

          <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            Mailing Address:
            <input
              name="mailingAddress"
              value={mailingAddress}
              onChange={this.onChange}
              type="text"
              placeholder="Street Address"
              class="form-control"
            />
          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="form-row">

          <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <input
              name="city"
              value={city}
              onChange={this.onChange}
              type="text"
              placeholder="City"
              class="form-control"
            />
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <select id="inputState" class="form-control" value={state} onChange={this.onChangeSelection}>
              <option selected>Choose a state</option>
              <option>...</option>
            </select>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-md-1">
            <input
              name="zip"
              value={zip}
              onChange={this.onChange}
              type="text"
              placeholder="Zip Code"
              class="form-control"
            />
          </div>

        </div>

        <button disabled={isInvalid} type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
          Sign Up
        </button>

        {error && <p>{error.message}</p>}
      </form>
    );
  }
}

const SignUpLink = () => (
  <p>
    Don't have an account? <Link to={ROUTES.SIGN_UP}>Sign Up</Link>
  </p>
);

const SignUpForm = compose(
  withRouter,
  withFirebase,
)(SignUpFormBase);

export default SignUpPage;

export { SignUpForm, SignUpLink };
```

Comment: When I do that, it will take inputs, but it breaks my isInvalid(). Do you know why this is happening? Why don't I need defaultValue for username or passwordOne/Two, or other fields. The only fields that won't work with value are firstName, middleName, lastName, and state, actually. I don't get it.

Comment: I implemented your code. take a look it works fine
`https://codesandbox.io/s/626o7v1y83`

Comment: It doesn't work with Firebase and initial_state, though.